# Localisation Laravel 8 not working in server

Tags: laravel, localization

I am trying to execute localisation in english and arabic.
In local it is working fine.
After that I followed this steps:
-change env file
-run npm run prod
-zip and copy the folder to server in public_html folder.

But in server I am just getting it as a link.

I am new to Laravel.Really appreciate if someone can help.

Comment: did you clear the cache `php artisan optimize:clear` ?

Comment: in local before uploading do we need to run this command?

Comment: On the server, when you changed the .env or route file. Configuration is cached in Laravel

Comment: Also before uploading to server..i edited .env in local to server credentials..den run npm prod..after that only I zipped and uploaded.Is that correct procedure?

Comment: You upload the Laravel app using FTP? I would advise you to use GIT. the .env file via FTP, and that could/should be different locally and on the server. Thats the point of the .env file (it's used for the configuration that is different in every environment)

Comment: not ftp uploading to a shared hosting server